# Is there a way to identify a http request which sends 200 status code but redirects to a page which displays 404 error

Tags: jmeter

i have a microsoft link which returns 200 status code but it displays 404 custom page. How to assert in jmeter and make the test case that this link is returning actually a broken link.

```
https://support.microsoft.com/kb/948590
```

which redirects to

```
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/948590
```

with 404 custom image page and below is the status it returns -

```
Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start: 2019-04-17 18:53:54 IST
Load time: 1282
Connect Time: 0
Latency: 626
Size in bytes: 107295
Sent bytes:214
Headers size in bytes: 1074
Body size in bytes: 106221
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 0
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: 200
Response message: OK
```

Expected i have such many url which has custom page which displays 404 which returns 200 status code.

How to make such url fail in jmeter

Answer (score 2):

This is actually something your developer should fix from their side when the set the HTTP response code. Do note that JMeter is a client side testing tool. It just goes with the HTTP Response message and Response code it gets from the server. It can not take decision based on some random text which could contain 404.

If you are a QA/Dev person and see this for your application, you should get this fixed. Till then you can parse the response text and decide the response is successful or not.

For ex:

You could fail this yourself by checking that `404PageController` is not present in your response.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A custom 404 page *should* still return a 404 status code. Drupal, for example, correctly returns a 404 code along with the custom theme, blocks, etc.

Looking at this in Chrome Web Dev, I see a later URL: `948590?iecbust=1555509641240`

That one correctly returns a 404, but it's from a XHR later in the page load. Probably something to do with Angular, but I'm not sure how you'd figure this one out from the original URL.